# Pymongo MongoDB - How do I remove an object from an array within an array with 3 values to index by

Tags: python, mongodb

This is my current collection

```
{
    "req_id": "c76372ee-e8d7-4c9e-81cb-d682fe069320",
    "data": [
        {target_num: 0, vehicle_list: [{vehicle_num: 0, paths_list: [{pair_id: 0}]}, {pair_id: 1}]}]},
        {target_num: 1, vehicle_list: [{vehicle_num: 0, paths_list: [{pair_id: 2}]}]},
            ]
}
```

I want to delete the object in the paths_list with pair_id 0.

I have:

- target_num: 0
- vehicle_num: 0
- pair_id: 0

How would I go about deleting it in python?

This is my attempt, but it doesn't work and i'm not sure why...

```
collection.update(
        {"_id": ObjectId(
            "t43z5e64b72e2f7816bfdx32")
        },
        {
            "$pull":
            {
                "data":
                {
                    "target_num": 0,
                    "vehicle_list": {
                        "vehicle_num": 0,
                        "paths_list": {
                            "pair_id": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$pull` with `arrayFilters`.

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $pull: {
    "data.$[d].vehicle_list.$[v].paths_list": {
      pair_id: 0
    }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "d.target_num": 0
    },
    {
      "v.vehicle_num": 0
    }
  ]
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iaJw0WNUWG6) for your reference.

Comment: I tried this: ".update_one(
            {},
            {
                '$pull': {
                    "data.$[d].vehicle_list.$[v].paths_list": {
                        pair_id: 0
                    }
                }
            },
            array_filters=[
                {
                    "d.target_num": 0
                },
                {
                    "v.vehicle_num": 0
                }
            ]
        )", but it doesn't seem to be having any effect on the db...

Comment: Is there any chance that your given example is a simplified one? The solution actually assumed `{ pair_id: 0 }` is a single-field object